# Improperly nested brackets regexp

Tags: python, regex, qregexp

I need a regexp that will find improperly nested brackets, not properly. For example:

```
()(( — matches regexp
(()) - doesn't match regexp
))((( — matches regexp
etc.
```

Comment: Regular expressions are not appropriate for this, unless you have a regexp engine that supports recursion.

Comment: @Barmar I guess the author of the question uses QRegExp.

Comment: @Barmar see eyllanesc's edit.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica I guess they're using Python's `re` module, which doesn't support recursion. [this website](http://rachbelaid.com/recursive-regular-experession/) mentions that you can install a PCRE library that does, and then shows how to use it to detect balanced parentheses.

Comment: @Barmar I use `QTextCharFormat.regexp_by_format()`.

Comment: OK, that apparently uses PCRE, so you should be able to use the solution at the website in my link.